# Do I need to wire the lamp via a relay?

Tags: battery-operated, halogen

I'm wiring my brother's bicycle with a **Philips Rally H4 Bulb 12V 130/100W**. He needs it for like 15-25 minutes everyday.
Since I have only a **12V 7Ah** battery and it is insufficient for this bulb as it will drain the battery really bad and damage it, I have connected the bulb to a **6V 10Ah** battery.

So the bulb wattage will be like **32.5W(current draw of 5.41A) & 25W(4.2A) at 6V** and its quite bright in my opinion.

I have a few questions:

1. Can I run both the filaments at once?(Total watts will be like **57.5W**)
2. Right now I have connected it directly through a **Universal Ignition Key Switch**, but it does heat up after running for 20 minutes. Do I need a **headlamp relay**?
3. Also what wire gauge would be the best. Right now I'm using 18 AWG I guess.
4. Will a 12V 10A fuse be enough?

Comment: For a 12V bulb you need a 12V battery, because at 6V the bulb will not be bright. 100W 12V bulb is an equivalent of a pretty strong car headlight. Is that appropriate for a bike?

Comment: running the 130W filament at 6V gives about 32.5W.Almost close to a 35W bike headlamp.If I run both filaments it will be above 50W.I thought this was fine.Also I have a spare 35W HID too with me.Using that on the 12V 7Ah I have should be fine since operating current is like 3A but I was worried if it might be illegal.

Comment: You're overlooking two things: (1) Light bulbs are non-linear - W has a positive tempco, so current at 6 volts will be > 1/2 current at 12 volts. (2) At reduced voltage the light will be browner, as well as dimmer.  A much larger portion of the light will be IR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need at least a 10A relay and pref 25A due to the bulb surge being 9x or so with no NTC soft start.  try this  . Life time on contacts reduced from 60k to 10k

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpCZDd.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Bulbs hi or low side. 10A slow blo